# How to trigger application inside S3 bucket using Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an application written in java which is used for creating and sending mail to users. I have zipped this code and uploaded this code to S3 bucket.

How can I trigger this application with the help of Lambda?

I have created a Lambda function and attached the path to Lambda.

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke the Lambda function, or are you asking how to have Lambda run your supplied code? What is happening at the moment if you click **Test**?

Comment: I'm getting class not found error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the Lambda function and pointed the function to your code, then Lambda will call the `handler` function within your code.

Lambda does not "run your application". Rather, it calls the handler, passing in information about how the function was invoked.

Comment: if I'm passing my main method in handler that is "package-name.classname::method" if i'm adding handler as "package-name.classname::main" will it execute my application.

Comment: See: [AWS Lambda Function Handler in Java - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html)

Comment: I will try this .Thanks for your response.